# PHP get object from array while creating object

Tags: php, arrays, object

Using this code:

```
$notis = [
    new InternalNotification([
       $this->receiver()->associate(User::first()->id),
        'product_id'        => 1,
        'notification_id'   => 1,
        'is_read'           => false,
    ]),
];
```

How can I make sure to get the current instance of `InternalNotification` on line 3 (`$this->`)?

Comment: You can't. `$this` refers to the object whose method contains that code.

Comment: Question doesn't make sense and your array there is looking a little funky. Is it associative or numeric? If you want a reference to the InternalNotification then assign it to a var, `$this` works inside methods, not inside an argument to the constructor.

Comment: You can't refer to the new instance in the arguments being sent to the constructor, because arguments are evaluated before calling the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question right, the answer is "you can't", for a fairly fundamental reason: it doesn't exist yet.

An expression in PHP (and most languages) is evaluated from the inside out - to give a simple example `var_dump(foo());` has to run function `foo()` before it can dump its output.

So your code is equivalent to this:

```php
$a = User::first()->id;
$b = $this->receiver()->associate($a);
$notis = [
    new InternalNotification([
        $b,
        'product_id'        => 1,
        'notification_id'   => 1,
        'is_read'           => false,
    ]),
];
```

There's no way for $b to see into the future and get the object that doesn't exist yet. The earliest you can access that object is in its constructor.